# Sinatra - Dashing.io setting timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, sinatra, dashing

I've been trying to set the timezone of a dashing.io app (which runs under sinatra) with no success at all!

Doing: `Time.zone` ends up with `NoMethodError - undefined method 'zone=' for Time:Class:`

I've tried the solution at [How to set timezone in ActiveSupport's TimeZone class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259840/how-to-set-timezone-in-activesupports-timezone-class) :

`require 'active_support/all'`

But then i get the error: `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/all (LoadError)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Support is not installed by default.

There are two stages of using third-party library's.

1. Installation
2. Registration

First things first, I assume that you follow the official guide on [dashing.io](http://dashing.io).

**stage 1 - Installation**

With this in place you can add the gem `activesupport` which you need for this in to your Gemfile. Just adding a line like this:

> gem 'activesupport'

After that you need to install it, you can do that with just running a second time `bundle` this fetch all gems and install it.

**stage 2 - Registration**

After you installed it, you can do what you tried with:

> require 'active_support/all'

This tell that you load the active_support library.

**THE END**

After this two simple steps you can use `Time.zone` as expected.

Comment: I figure out to this eventually however it seems that i have no idea how to use the Time.zone thing. I placed it in the config.ru and when tried to use it in a view it would still give me the central time. I ended just just creating a variable in the view called time_adjustment and add it to all the times i want to use a time operation.